# Counting lines without text in a file

Tags: wc

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 for a while now, programming in C++ and Python. I have some question that I can solve by making a program, but maybe there are easier ways, so here is the first question.

I can use `grep` to find lines with a word/pattern and then use `wc` to count them:

```
grep word somefile | wc -l
```

How do I count the lines that have no "text"? Those that are empty or have only spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your system should have GNU grep, that has an option `-P` to use Perl expressions and you can use that, combined with `-c` (so no need for `wc -l`):

```
grep -Pvc '\S' somefile
```

The `'\S'` hands the pattern `\S` to grep and matches all line containing anything that is not space, `-v` selects all the other lines (those only with space), and `-c` counts them.

From the man page for grep:

```
-P, --perl-regexp
       Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  Perl  regular  expression  (PCRE, see
       below).  This is highly experimental and grep  -P  may  warn  of
       unimplemented features.

-v, --invert-match
       Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
       is specified by POSIX.)

-c, --count
       Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching  lines
       for  each  input  file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see
       below), count non-matching lines.  (-c is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: If you don't want to use the 'highly experimental' `-P` or don't have gnu `grep`, then `grep -Ec '^[[:space:]]*$' somefile` should work (works the same way). I have `+1`'d anyway as who doesn't have gnu `grep` these days...

Comment: @abligh, MacOS, *BSD, propietary Unices, ...

Comment: Sure (that's why I gave the alternative). OS-X `grep` does have `-P` and has done since (at least) 10.6.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep` for it:

```
$ grep -c '^[     ]*$' somefile
```

where `^`/`$` match the start/end of a line and `[     ]` specifies the character class that includes space and tab characters. `*` denote 0 to unlimited repetitions of the left hand side.

The `-c` option tells grep to count the lines matching the pattern - instead of printing them to the terminal.

Note that on `zsh` I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter a literal tab character.

(a `[ \t]` is not recognized by `grep`)

Comment: Personally, I find Timo's solution much cleaner. This requires you to type those characters manually. But here's a +1!

Comment: @AmalMurali, it's a matter of taste, of course - but perhaps not everybody is familiar (or wants to be familiar) with all of Perl's regex extensions ... (not to talk about grep versions without `-P` support ...)